# Does Google Search App block universal links

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, firebase-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I am implementing Firebase App Indexing as mentioned in official firebase documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/ios/app.

The universal links are enabled and work fine for search results from different browsers like Safari and Chrome. They also work for other applications. But when I tap on a search result from the Google Search App in iOS. It does not take me to my app. Also on long pressing a link in the Google app does not provide an option to open link using my App. This option is however shown when I long press on links from other applications.

Does it have something to do with the Google Search app disabling the universal links deliberately. Is it possible for individual applications to prevent Universal Links from opening other applications?

Or does Apple apply restrictions itself for certain apps?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, some apps disable the capability of deep linking using Universal Links. Some notable examples: `Facebook`, `Instagram`.

Some of these apps allow deep linking via URI schemes (the old iOS 9- way of deep linking), but there is no promise that this behaviour will be persisted.

I'm guessing most of these apps would like to have the user stay within their own in-app browser instead of switching to another app.

I never tried the Google Search app, but if your universal link works perfectly in Safari and not in the Google Search app, that may be the case. In that scenario you'll need your click domain server to redirect the user to the store or some landing page, based on the User Agent of the incoming browser.